# Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 is the error I receive

Tags: php, mysql

When I try to add an entry into my SQL Database from a form  I get the following Error:
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

My Sql Code is as follows:

```
$name = $_POST['input4'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$projectnumber = $_POST['input1'];
$area   = $_POST['input2'];
$donebefore = $_POST['radio9'];
$changesmade    = $_POST['radio8'];
$safeaccess = $_POST['radio11'];
$electrical = $_POST['radio5'];
$machineguarding    = $_POST['radio6'];
$correctequipment   = $_POST['radio4'];
$sds    = $_POST['radio3'];
$controltoxic   = $_POST['radio1'];
$ppe    = $_POST['radio2'];
$hazard = $_POST['checkbox[]'];
$otherhazards   = $_POST['input3'];
$controlofhazards   = $_POST['checkbox1[]'];
$monitor    = $_POST['radio12'];
$comments   = $_POST['input'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO hira (Name, TodayDate, ProjectNumber, Area,
                        DoneBefore, HaveChangesMade, SafeAccess,
                        ElectricalEquipment, MachineGuarding, CorrectEquipment,          
                        SDS, ControlToxic, PPE, Hazard,
                        OtherHazard, ControlHazard, MonitorProcess, AdditionalComments)
        VALUES ('$name', '$date','$projectnumber','$area',
                       '$donebefore','$changesmade','$safeaccess',
                       '$electrical','$machineguarding','$correctequipment',
                       '$sds','$controltoxic','$ppe',''$hazard',
                        $otherhazards','$controlofhazards','$monitor','$comments')";
```

Is there something I overlooked?
Thanks in advance

Comment: "Is there something I overlooked?" yes sql injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'$ppe',''$hazard',$otherhazards','$controlofhazards','$monitor','$comments')";
```

see this is the issue before $hazard you have two single quotes

Comment: if you are using mysql then use mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['input4']), for all inputs you are getting

Comment: @AndreasKrüger use mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['input4']), for all inputs you are getting